# Php if else yes/no

Tags: php, html, if-statement

am trying to add a function to a script where a user is ask for code, which i have added. but having one issue of i want to unable when to ask the user code and when to to ask  . 
so i need a php if else and it sql 
so when i unable to ask code for a user it will ask code and when i disable it wont ask code 
below is the one i have tried

```
if ((['yes'])) {
  // Yes

<div id="cot_div" align="center">
    <p>Please enter your <strong id="code_up">COT</strong> code to continue</p>



    <form id="form3" name="form3" method="POST" action="inter_suc.php">  
   <table border="0" id="trans" align="center" >
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding:0px"><span id="sprytextfield1">
      <input name="cot" type="text" id="cot" size="10" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>

      <span id="sprytextfield2">
      <input name="tax" type="text" id="tax" size="10" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>
      <span id="sprytextfield3">
      <input name="imf" type="text" id="imf" size="10"  />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span><br />  <span id="error">
      wrong COT Code</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding:0px"><input type="button" name="go" id="go" value="Go" />
      <input type="button" name="go2" id="go2" value="GO" />
      <input type="button" name="go3" id="go3" value="GO" />

    </td>
  </tr>

} else {
  // No

<div id="cot_div" align="center">
    <p>Please enter your <strong id="code_up">COT</strong> code to continue</p>



    <form id="form3" name="form3" method="POST" action="inter_suc.php">  
   <table border="0" id="trans" align="center" >
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding:0px"><span id="sprytextfield1">
        <input name="cot" type="hidden" id="cot" value="<?php echo $_POST['cot'];?>" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>

      <span id="sprytextfield2">
      <input name="tax" type="hidden" id="tax" value="<?php echo $_POST['tax'];?>" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>
      <span id="sprytextfield3">
       <input name="imf" type="hidden" id="imf" value="<?php echo $_POST['imf'];?>" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span><br />  <span id="error">
      wrong COT Code</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding:0px"><input type="button" name="go" id="go" value="Go" />
      <input type="button" name="go2" id="go2" value="GO" />
      <input type="button" name="go3" id="go3" value="GO" />

    </td>
  </tr>

}
```

Comment: your question is very unclear, please look into the question and edit it

Comment: also, you are trying to use html inside a php statement, wich is not possible the way you did it(put the html inside an echo or escape php). and the `<form>` has no closing tag

Comment: ok am trying to add unable form and auto fill form so it can bypass it with sql insect in user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys thank for your help i thin i get it

```
<?php if ($yes = $_GET["yes"] == "yes"): ?>


html code to run if condition is empty 

<?php else: ?>

html code to run if condition is yes

<?php endif ?>
```

if the == "yes" is yes it show yes condition but if empty it show the empty part

Answer (score 0):

Ιf I understand your answered correct, than you want to display a specific HTML part if a given variable in php is 'yes'. Otherwise you want to show a different part of the HTML.

Then you can use this syntax:

```
<?php if ($val == 'YES'): ?>
  <!-- Yes part -->
<?php else: ?>
  <!-- No part -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: how do i handle if the val is yes it will show yes part and if no it will show no part

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```css
.error {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<?php
  $yes = $_GET["yes"] == "yes"; ?>
<div id="cot_div" align="center">
  <p>Please enter your <strong id="code_up">COT</strong> code to continue</p>
  <form id="form3" name="form3" method="POST" action="inter_suc.php">
    <table border="0" id="trans" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="padding:0px">
          <span id="sprytextfield1"><input name="cot" type="<?php echo $yes ? "text" : "hidden"; ?>" id="cot" size="10" /></span>
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span>
          <span id="sprytextfield2"><input name="tax" type="<?php echo $yes ? "text" : "hidden"; ?>" id="tax" size="10" /></span>
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span>
          <span id="sprytextfield3"><input name="imf" type="<?php echo $yes ? "text" : "hidden"; ?>" id="imf" size="10"  /></span>    
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span><br /> 
          <span id="error">wrong COT Code</span>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="padding:0px">
        <input type="button" name="go" id="go" value="Go" />
        <input type="button" name="go2" id="go2" value="GO" />
        <input type="button" name="go3" id="go3" value="GO" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: <?php if ($yes = $_GET["yes"] == "yes"): ?>

html code to run if condition is yes

<?php else: ?>

html code to run if condition is no

<?php endif ?> i run this but only show no part

Comment: bro pls can u help me i wan to create a column and use it in unable and disabling